# Selectively disable rotation on views managed by UITabBarViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, rotation, autorotate

In my App, I have a `tabbarController` and 5 view controllers managed by it.

I only want one `UIView` rotate to landscape and make the tabbar invisible when rotate to landscape. In current condition, all my views autorotate themselves which is not what I expect.

The code of `UIView` which I dont want it rotate is:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation     duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        // stop the rotation, keep it as portrait orientation
        // from app document, it says for UITabbarController, rootview which is   uitabbarcontroller and views managed by it should all agree on the same orientation otherwise they wont rotate.
        // how can i do this?
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```